# How to record stored procedure execution run time

Tags: sql-server

Just looking for some help with a stored procedure in SQL Server. I have commonly come across the following code:

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime
DECLARE @EndTime datetime
SELECT @StartTime=GETDATE() 

 -- Write Your Query


SELECT @EndTime=GETDATE()

--This will return execution time of your query
SELECT DATEDIFF(MS,@StartTime,@EndTime) AS [Duration in millisecs]
```

This only saves the data in the output panel(Messages). I was wondering if it was possible to save the results of the run time for the script each time into a table. For example a table that could look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Job_Batch(
    JobID NVARCHAR(MAX),
    JobDate NVARCHAR(MAX),
    JobTime NVARCHAR(MAX),
    JobDuration NVARCHAR(MAX),
    JobStatus NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

The script should also be able to generate its own JobID each time its run.

Comment: Select either MySQL or SQL Server (MS SQL) - this is two different DBMSs. Looking the syntax MySQL is not correct - edit and re-tag your question.

Comment: Why would you have everything as NVARCHAR(MAX) ?  Especially storing date and time values - that makes no sense.    At which point do you care about the execution time - at the end of your Stored Proc logic or after it has inserted the batch info?  Surely you can write an ```INSERT``` statement - so what part of this do you need help with?  Be more explicit please.

Comment: Sure you can, use an insert statement like normal.

Comment: What you posted *returns the duration to the client*, it doesn't print it

Comment: Apart from that, what you describe is the SQL Server Agent and its tables. If you want to get IDs, execution times, durations, schedules and a lot more, create a SQL Server Agent job. You can check a job's history by [querying the sysjobhistory table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2850/querying-sql-server-agent-job-history-data/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm changing your table up a bit just to capture things a little better:

```
declare @job_batch table (
    JobId int identity(1,1),
    JobName varchar(255),
    JobDate datetime,
    JobElapsedMs int,
    JobStatus nvarchar(4000)
);
```

Let me make a sample and temporary procedure to test the concept:

```
create or alter procedure #dummyProc as
begin
    declare @i int = 0;
    while @i < 100000 
    begin
        set @i += 1;
    end
end
```

This code below demonstrates putting the needed information into the logging table:

```
declare 
    @StartTime datetime = getdate(),
    @JobStatus nvarchar(4000);

begin try
    exec #dummyProc
    set @JobStatus = 'Success';
end try
begin catch
    set @JobStatus = error_message();
end catch

insert  @job_batch (JobName, JobDate, JobElapsedMs, JobStatus)
values  ('#dummyProc', @StartTime, datediff(ms,@StartTime,getdate()), @JobStatus);
```

When you query the @job_batch table:

```
select * from @job_batch;
```

You get this:

```
+-------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+
| JobId |   JobName  |          JobDate        | JobElapsedMs | Job Status |
+-------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+
|   1   | #dummyProc | 2021-01-28 00:22:57.370 |     60       |  Success   |
+-------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+------------+
```